# Could you give me the simular code from sqlserver to mysql

Tags: mysql, hierarchy, recursive-query

We have

[this following data][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFSzj.png

Here, we are showing all the possible parent Ids at the column with a specific separator ‘.’

```
WITH Hierarchy(ChildId, ChildName, ParentId, Parents)
AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM UserType AS FirtGeneration
        WHERE ParentId IS NULL    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NextGeneration.Id, NextGeneration.Name, Parent.ChildId,
    CAST(CASE WHEN Parent.Parents = ''
        THEN(CAST(NextGeneration.ParentId AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
        ELSE(Parent.Parents + '.' + CAST(NextGeneration.ParentId AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
    END AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM UserType AS NextGeneration
        INNER JOIN Hierarchy AS Parent ON NextGeneration.ParentId = Parent.ChildId    
)
SELECT *
    FROM Hierarchy
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

[the results give: ][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV5Xw.png

Do you know how i could have the equivalent with mysql ?

Comment: 1) Replace all string addition with CONCAT() function. 2) All CAST must be removed. 3) Max recursion depth must be set separately via session according variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE descendants AS
(
SELECT id, name, CAST(Name AS CHAR(500)) AS path
FROM usertype  
where parent_id is null
UNION ALL
SELECT t.id, t.name, CONCAT(d.path, ',', t.name)
FROM descendants d, usertype t
WHERE t.parent_id = d.id
)
SELECT * FROM descendants ORDER BY path;
```